# How to make sure a python function has no dependence on external variables?

Tags: python, debugging, syntax, functional-programming, functional-testing

Suppose I have defined a function `f(x)`, which is syntactically correct.  I want to make sure that `f` works "functionally", in the sense that its output depends solely on the input `x`.

Sometimes, if the definition of `f` is complicated, one may unintentionally (because of a typo, or just not being careful enough) refer to some external variables in its definition, which can cause bugs that are difficult to find out.

Is there any tool, any "directive pragma" (so to say), or any "best practice" to make sure this does not happen?

Example:

```
xx = 1.0

def f(x, y, p=1):
    return xx * y**p # A typo here: should be x * y**p
```

If there is no simple way to achieve this in python, which languages have such a feature?  As far as I know, C, C++, and Fortran does not have this.  Fortran 95 has pure subroutines and functions, but it is used by the programmer to "promise" a subroutine/function will not modify any external variables, while the subroutine/function can still take value from them.

Comment: Well, there's always the quick and dirty way

Answer (score 2):

Although it's a little hackish, you could do something like this which checks the instructions used in the function's code object:

```
import opcode  # see /Python/Lib/opcode.py

GLOBAL_INSTRUCTIONS = {opcode.opmap['DELETE_GLOBAL'],
                       opcode.opmap['LOAD_GLOBAL'],
                       opcode.opmap['STORE_GLOBAL']}

def is_pure(func):
    for inst in instructions(func.func_code.co_code):
        op = inst[0]
        if op in GLOBAL_INSTRUCTIONS:
            return False
    return True

def instructions(code):
    """Iterates over a code string yielding integer [op, arg] pairs
    """
    code = map(ord, code)
    i, L = 0, len(code)
    extended_arg = 0
    while i < L:
        op = code[i]
        i+= 1
        if op < opcode.HAVE_ARGUMENT:
            yield [op, None]
            continue
        oparg = code[i] + (code[i+1] << 8) + extended_arg
        extended_arg = 0
        i += 2
        if op == opcode.EXTENDED_ARG:
            extended_arg = oparg << 16
            continue
        yield [op, oparg]

xx = 1.0

def f(x, y, p=1):
    return xx * y**p # A typo here: should be x * y**p

def f2(x, y, p=1):
    return x * y**p # No typo

print(is_pure(f))   # --> False
print(is_pure(f2))  # --> True
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with - you can ask your question just as "How to check if my function is pure".

Answer - it's impossible in python. Don't look. Also, if you want to check purity in your code, you probably 'd be better with another language.

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally possible in python. If you want a language which enforces pure functions and referential transparency, try using [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).